# Discord.js command handling - Problems with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

After following the Discord.js tutorial on command handling (https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/adding-features.html), I can't find how to declare my variables in all my files.

For example, here's what I said in my index.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
const adapter = new FileSync('./db.json')
const db = low(adapter)
const adapter2 = new FileSync('./tokens.json')
const tokens = low(adapter2)
const adapter3 = new FileSync('./usedTokens.json')
const used = low(adapter3)
const prefix = config.prefix;
const version = config.version;
```

If I add a file containing a command in ./commands/command I am obliged to redeclare all my variables previously entered in my index.js:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'profile',
    description: 'Checker les infos de son profil avec la commande !profile',
    execute(message, args) {
    //Déclaration de toute les variables
    const low = require('lowdb')
    const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')
    const adapter = new FileSync('./db.json')
    const db = low(adapter)
    const adapter2 = new FileSync('./tokens.json')
    const tokens = low(adapter2)
    const adapter3 = new FileSync('./usedTokens.json')
    const used = low(adapter3)
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const version = config.version;
    var config = require('../config.json');
```

I'm looking for a solution so I don't have to re-declare everything in each new command file...

Comment: Unrelated, but using `FileSync` for a bot is a poor idea - during all database operations, the bot will freeze while waiting for file i/o to complete, unable to take any further commands. To remedy this you really ought to use `FileAsync` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like 95% of your issue is your database stuff. Your database stuff should be loaded exactly once, and then you should absolutely pass it around as "context" to your commands. In discord.js I personally like sticking such things on the client instance, because it's guaranteed to be passed around everywhere you might need it.

`index.js`:

```
client.db = { users: db, tokens: tokens, used: used };
```

`./commands/command.js`:

```
execute(message, args) {
  let client = message.client;
  let token = client.db.tokens.get(message.author.id); //for example
  //do other stuff
}
```

Worth noting also: you most likely *don't* need to redeclare all of your variables anyway. Are you using `version` in this command specifically? What about `Discord`? If you don't use them, don't import them.